# Instatiate a row of objects unity creating a new gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am trying to make a road between two cities

Now I have a middle point

```
var center = Vector3.Lerp(city1.transform.position, city2.transform.position, 0.5f);
```

I create an empty road object with a connected script on it

```
GameObject road = PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(empty_road) as GameObject;
```

A `road_part` prefab (a small rectangle with white lines in the center) should be used to instantiate a sufficient number of `road_part` objects. But how to do it if I don't know the "physical" size of the `road_part`'s model?

Comment: What do you mean by not knowing the size of the road_part?? it's a prefab (as you have described) so the size will be the same as the size of the prefab

Comment: btw instead of using `Lerp` you could use the better understandable `(city1.transform.position + city2.transform.position) / 2f;`

Comment: well and somehow you have to get the size of the `road_part` then ... you could e.g. use the [`Renderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) in order to get the world size - limitation: it will be alligned with the world XYZ axis

Comment: @Gray_Rhino if we have a cube with values scale 1 it has a side length of 1 unit. My road_part can be 1.5x2 units x and z respectively, or other values can, it depends on the model I use. And this size I want to use to estimate how many objects do I need to instantiate

Comment: @miduja what we mean is if it is a prefab you usually should know it's sizes .. so it is a bit unclear where the exact problem is .. 1. You have to define which space you want to fill 2. devide that space by size of the Roadpart -> result is the amount of parts needed

Comment: @derHugo `>>devide that space by size of the Roadpart`

that is my question, how to get the size of the roadpart?

Comment: @miduja derHugo already explained you can use [`Renderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) if it's aligned with the world XYZ axes.